Is there a way to redirect www.domain.com links to domain.com?
My website keeps getting referrals, but the referrals are mislabeled as "www.domain.com". My site is a non-www site, so anytime someone tries to directly search our website or click the referral links, they are given an error. Is there a way, either through my .htaccess file or within my DNS settings, to fix this?
Extra info: My site is built through WordPress, hosted by GoDaddy, and my domain is managed by Ionos.
I have tried to go into my dns settings to fix this before, but to no avail. I added a CNAME record with a hostname of www to domain.com. I have not tried adding an A record due to the fact a large tool for our business is being directed to another A record and I don't want to mess it up.

Sure you can redirect such requests. You will literally find hundreds of working examples here on SO. Just a simple search. But before you can redirect such requests you need to make sure that your http server actually reacts to those requests. That is something that has nothing to do with rewriting or with a distributed configuration file (".htaccess") but with how names are resolved and how your http server's hosts are configured and whether your SSL certificate is actually valid for that "www hostname".
